# What is the default data structure in C?

Tags: c, data-structures

I encountered an problem and i cant able to find answer of the question anywhere would anyone help me to know "What is the default data structure in C ?"

Comment: "Array" would be my guess, but I'd argue that there is no such thing as default data structure in C. --- "Default" would seem to imply that you tell C to put your data in a structure, but you don't specify which, so it goes ahead and stores it as an array... this is far from true.

Comment: This question does not make any sense to me either.  OP - where did that come from?

Comment: i faced this question in the entrance exam of cdac , is this question is wrong?

Comment: If you mean built in data structures then it is arrays and `struct`s.

Comment: @MartinJames; From "default" planet.

Comment: @Piyush Zalani There is no such a notion like "default data structure" in C.:)

Comment: Is the answer `int`? (ref function arguments and return values).

Answer (score 1):

I just had a quick scan through the K&R (Kernighan and Ritchie - The C Programming Language) book in the chapter on structures and there is no mention of a 'default data structure'. I certainly never heard of a default data structure when I was doing 'C' programming but just checked in case I had forgotten something from long ago.

As a suggestion, could it be interpreted as a trick question where the answer is 'none' or 'not applicable'?

Answer (score 0):

When only a storage class is given, the type is assumed to be `int`. These are all legal and declare an integer, so if anything can be said to be the "default" data structure, `int` is it.

```
static var1;

int func()
{
    auto var2;
    register var3;
 }
```

(Yeah, still a dumb question [in the sense that "default data structure" is not a well-defined concept or term of art, and even experts wouldn't necessarily know what is being asked].)